# Как продолжить поток, выполнив другой метод c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Создаю потоки, которые присоединяются к серверу с нескольких аккаунтов.
Они работают, все отлично. Но они, как бы, неуправляемые.
Если хочу отправить или сделать что-нибудь в определенном потоке, то это вводит меня в ступор. Не могу понять, как обратиться к рабочему потоку, при этом отправив ему метод.

Вот так создаю потоки:

```
public void thrd()
    {
        thread = new Thread[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < Global.countthread; i++)
        {
            thread[i] = new Thread(this.Checking);
            thread[i].IsBackground = true;
            thread[i].Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Иосиф Виссарионович, а почему не `Task`?

Comment: Что вы называете рабочим потоком? Если это UI поток, отправить ему метод можно с помощью `SynchronizationContext.Send` (синхронно) или `SynchronizationContext.Post` (асинхронно), при этом нужно иметь ссылку на `SynchronizationContext` UI потока, который можно получить, например, в конструкторе формы, или что у вас там.